# Neither for nor while loop run in linear time O(n) in python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop, runtime

I measured the runtimes of a for and a while loop in python and plotted them with `matplotlib`.
To my surprise, the graphs aren't looking that linear, especially the one of the `for` loop. It also took longer to loop through 600k numbers than it took to loop through 700k.

What did I do wrong or is it just python which does things differently?

```
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

time_while=[]
time_for=[]
for i in range(200000, 1000000+1, 100000):
    t1 = time.time()
    n = 0
    while n < i:
        n += 1
    t2 = time.time()
    time_while.append(round(t2-t1,5))

    t1 = time.time()
    for n in range(i):
       n=n
    t2 = time.time()
    time_for.append(round(t2-t1,5))

x=["200k","300k","400k","500k","600k","700k","800k","900k","1Mio",]
plt.plot(x, time_while,label="while")
plt.plot(x, time_for,label="for")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: hard to say with 9 datapoints, but it looks linear to me with some noise present.

Comment: Just tried your code, and got a completely linear result. I think there needs to be more "meat" in each loop to get something accurate, as it runs so quick that very small fluctuations in available capacity on your cores cause the picture to be skewed

Comment: @oskros so you've got a straight line without any noise at all? So I did it again with 1000 data points and now it looks kinda linear, but I still got a lot of fluctuations. Is there anyway to get rid of that or is that just normal?

Comment: How does it look like when you use `time.perf_counter` instead?

Comment: So, what other tasks is your computer doing while you are running your code? Can you control any of that to eliminate the possibility it is affecting what you see?

Comment: @KellyBundy yeah it looks quite similar (I don't know how to post a picture in the comments)

Comment: @quamrana I closed every program which was running in the background, and it still looks the same. If I'm using more data points I'm getting a graph which is kinda linear but has a lot of fluctuations

Comment: What about the other things that the computer is doing? Do you have anything which might be automatically running in the background in a schedule?

Comment: @quamrana nothing I would knew about. Maybe Windows is doing some things in the background,but I'm not sure about it. So you think these background tasks could be the reasons for my fluctuations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By making a slight modification to your code, adding a small summation within each loop I prolong the calculation time and the result will be more stable in terms of small fluctuations in available capacity on your cores. With this approach you clearly see the linearity that is expected.

The plot looks like this

[image: Loop comparison]

You can see the code used below

```py
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

time_while=[]
time_for=[]
for i in range(200000, 1000000+1, 100000):
    t1 = time.time()
    n = 0
    while n < i:
        sum(k for k in range(10))
        n += 1
    t2 = time.time()
    time_while.append(round(t2-t1,5))

    t1 = time.time()
    for n in range(i):
        sum(k for k in range(10))
        n=n
    t2 = time.time()
    time_for.append(round(t2-t1,5))

x=["200k","300k","400k","500k","600k","700k","800k","900k","1Mio",]
plt.plot(x, time_while,label="while")
plt.plot(x, time_for,label="for")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you reproduce their less nice curves with their original code? Just to be sure it's not just let's say your system having a more precise `time.time`...

Comment: @KellyBundy Yes, curves are a bit random. Ran it a few times with the original code, and one of the runs produced something similar to the original picture.

Comment: @oskros I run your code a few times and I didn't got such a perfect result like you, but at least it looks way better than before :) [I uploadet a picture of it here] (https://ibb.co/c6zJ3zN)

Comment: @maxpower you can probably increase the sum range in the loops and it will look more linear (and run a bit slower)